# C# web-api post to function with two parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post two parameters to the following function but I dont manage to reach the function:

```
public void SetShopSubCategories([FromBody]string userId, int []subCategories )
{

}
```

**This is how I post:**

```
var subCategories = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var userId = "123";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Category/SetShopSubCategories/",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(userId, subCategories),
                success: function () {
                    alert("OK");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
```

**When I post only with one parameter it goes well and I can reach the function:**

```
public void SetShopSubCategories([FromBody]string userId )
{

}

var userId = "123";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Category/SetShopSubCategories/",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(userId, subCategories),
            success: function () {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
```

**This one also goes well:**

```
public void SetShopSubCategories( int []subCategories )
{

}

var subCategories = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Category/SetShopSubCategories/",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(subCategories),
                success: function () {
                    alert("OK");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
```

**My RoutConfig:**

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "SetCategories",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model

```
public class Mymodel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }        
        public int[] subCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public void SetShopSubCategories([FromBody]Mymodel model)
        {

        }
```

Ajax Call:

```
var subCategories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var userId = "123"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/Values",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    data: JSON.stringify({ userid: userId, subCategories: subCategories }),
    success: function () {
        alert("OK");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Here is the link : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

you will find that multiple parameter not allowed or problematic due to type of stream.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.

Comment: If you have to support multiple than you have to build many thing from custom FromBody to how it binds and even you have to store your stream is custom buffer and all that.

Answer (score 0):

try below code and also add `dataType: 'json'`

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Category/SetShopSubCategories",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ userId  : userId, subCategories : subCategories}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
```

Comment: Still cannot reach the function.

Comment: why have you put [FromBody] here? @Eyal

Answer (score 0):

Change your route config to accept two parameters : *either update or add anew route with a different name*

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{category}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, category= UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Comment: Still cannot reach the function.